# Laravel 5 ORM update request, like date_add

Tags: php, laravel-4, orm, laravel-5

I beg to excuse me for my poor english.
So, I have Laravel 5 ORM, and i need to make request that should add date to some rows, like MySQL DATE_ADD. **Input** is **single date interval** and **array of id's**, **output** is **rows of database, that was changed by adding date interval**. Ideally, it should be one ORM request. I know that it is possible to use "bad" way and get all rows, update it in a code, and insert to database, but imho it's not good.
I hope answer will be link to some help site or some code if it's does not complicate you. Thanks for your attention!

```
    public function update($id)
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $rep_task = RepTask::find($id);
    $cl_task = \Request::has('json') ? json_decode(\Request::input('json'),true) : \Request::all();
    $ids = [];
    $task_id = $rep_task->task_id;
    $rep_tasks = RepTask::where('task_id', '=', $task_id)
        ->select('id')
        ->get();

    $new_date = date_create_from_format(self::DATE_FULLCALENDAR_FORMAT, $cl_task['new_date']);
    $selected_task_date = date_create_from_format(self::DATE_MYSQL_FORMAT, $rep_task->start_date);
    $diff = date_diff($selected_task_date, $new_date);


    if(\Request::has('json'))
    {
        $ids = [1,2,3]; //this for easy understanding

        DB::table('rep_task')
            ->whereIn('id', $ids)
            ->update(['start_date' => DB::raw('DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL ' . $diff->d . '  DAY)')]);

        $out_json = ['updated' => $ids];

        return json_encode($out_json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
    else
    {
        $start_date = 0;
        $end_date = 0;
        if (!isset($cl_task['name']) || !isset($cl_task['text']))
            return "{'error':'columns are not defined'}";
        if (isset($cl_task['start_date']) && isset($cl_task['end_date']))
        {
            $dt = date_create_from_format(self::DATE_FULLCALENDAR_FORMAT, $cl_task['start_date']);
            $start_date = $dt->format(self::DATE_MYSQL_FORMAT);
            $dt = date_create_from_format(self::DATE_FULLCALENDAR_FORMAT,$cl_task['end_date']);
            $end_date = $dt->format(self::DATE_MYSQL_FORMAT);
        }
        $rep_task->name = $cl_task['name'];
        $rep_task->text = $cl_task['text'];
        $rep_task->start_date = $start_date;
        $rep_task->end_date = $end_date;
        $rep_task->users_id = $user_id;
        $rep_task->save();
    }
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $tasks = Task::getAllTasksByUserFullcalendar($user_id);

    return view(
        'task.index',
        [
            'tasks' => $tasks
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code you have tried?

Comment: Look at changed post, after if(\Request::has('json')), there request with DB:raw, it is possible to change this by using ORM?